# Where is the rendered response persisted in Phoenix?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
defmodule TwittEx.PageController do
  require IEx
  use TwittEx.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    text conn, "hello"
    "dummy string so text/2 isn't returned"
  end
end
```

I come from Rails and understand what controllers are supposed to do, but can't understand how the magic happens in Phoenix. Elixir is stateless, so `conn` and `_params` cannot be modified. How does `text conn, "hello"` remember "hello" as I don't return it from index.

I suspect there is another process that keeps track of response. If so, does that mean a single vanilla request has more than one process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does `text conn, "hello"` remember "hello" as I don't return it from index.

It doesn't! The response (in this case "hello") is written to the `conn` immediately after you call `text`. You can test this out using the following:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  :timer.sleep(1000)
  conn = text conn, "hello"
  :timer.sleep(5000)
  conn
end
```

If you visit this page, you'll see the response in just over 1 second, not 6 seconds.

If you try to call `text` on the new `conn` returned by `text`, you'll get a `Plug.Conn.AlreadySentError` error as the new struct's `state` is `:sent`. If you try to call it twice on the same `conn` though, there's no error and the second write is ignored. I'm pretty sure it is the responsibility of the Plug Handler to ignore the second write as I just verified that `Plug` just calls the handler's `send_resp` again if you do that.